# IntelliJ IDEA no code completion for Java 10 'var'?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-completion, java-10

Recently I installed the new version (2018.1) of IntelliJ IDEA, which added support for Java 10.

But when I trying to use the `var` (for local variable type inference), I found there was no `var` in the code completion list. (See the screenshot below)

If I continue typing, it will apply `VarHandle` as the first suggestion in that list. Then I have to undo that completion to restore `var`.

I have checked project settings, I use JDK 10 and the language level is also set to 10. Code like `var number = 1;` compiles well. And I couldn't find anything about this in IDE settings.

What am I doing wrong? I just want to use `var` declaration without interruption.

[image: Code Completion]

Comment: Looks like its a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189285#comment=27-2791283

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  My suggestion would be to add a live template for `var` that simply expands back to `var`.  It’s a hack, but you can remove it once the issue is resolved.

Comment: @MikeStrobel The template hack works, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Did you try with the latest EAP?

Comment: It would really annoy me if my IDE was interpreting pressing *space* as “insert some word” instead of “insert *space*”. But I’m very confident that IntelliJ also has an option to use a different key (e.g. *enter*) for completion instead of *space*, to allow inserting *space* when pressing *space* (assuming you don’t want to “complete” `var` to `var`)…

Comment: @LppEdd No, now that there is a solution, I'm not willing to meet more bugs in EAP.

Comment: @Holger Well, it's also a nice solution. But I really like hitting space for completion :)

Comment: @GrantHoward I always use EAPs and I've never encountered a blocking bug.

Comment: @LppEdd OK, I'll try it next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Vic pointed out, this [appears to be a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189285).  Until it gets fixed, you can create a custom live template as a workaround.

Create a live template triggered by the `var` abbreviation, then enter `var` as the template text.  Make it available in the Java statement context.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

[Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189285#comment=27-2791283) has been fixed in upcoming IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 release:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ *(currently EAP version)*